# cannot configure MPICH. The selected Fortran 90 compiler gfortran does not work with the selected Fortran 77 compiler gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, mpich, gcc4

Experts: Am trying to configure MPICH-3.2b1 with this command:

> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mpi64-32-mpich CFLAGS="-m64"
>   FFLAGS="-m64" CC=gcc FC=gfortran
>
> ...
>
> configure: error: The selected Fortran 90 compiler gfortran does not
>   work with the selected Fortran 77 compiler gfortran.  Use the
>   environment variables FC and F77 respectively to select compatible
>   Fortran compilers.  The check here tests to see if a main program
>   compiled with the Fortran 90 compiler can link with a subroutine
>   compiled with the Fortran 77 compiler.

I've tried various invocations fo FC and F77 variables. Is this a deficiency in our (custom) build of gcc/gfortran 4.8?

Answer (score 1):

autoconf-generated configure scripts (which MPICH uses) record a ton of information in config.log.  Whenver configure scripts behave in a strange way, take a look at config.log for a clue.

One needs to be a bit careful here, as config.log will report many failures when it checks, for example, if one of your system calls behaves like an HP-UX 10.4 version (it won't).

but, look for 'gfortran' and other context so you can find the test.  Sometimes this type of error is due to a missing library or header file: perhaps you simply need to update an environment variable.

Comment: Rob, i think this will be related, yes, to intricacies of the environment or the build script. Will have to spend a bit more time on it. Thanks!